# Условие: если не попадает ни в 1 switch/case

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, switch

Пишу бота и у меня в нем есть клавиатура и обработка force_reply

Т.е. - это реализовано двумя свитчами - один отвечает за обработку клавиатуры, а второй смотрит поле `msg.reply_to_message.text`

Теперь мне нужно написать дефолтное действие, с условием - если ни в 1 свитч сообщение пользователя не попало то вывести главное меню

Comment: Думаю в обоих случаях выполнить функцию одну и туже будет достаточно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделай boolean переменную, в которой укажи что если попадает в case, устанавливай её в true, потом просто проверь эту переменную, если false то case не отработали